# Upper bound for Gamma Function.

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function, upper-lower-bounds

Gamma function is $\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt$. This is an integral that depends on a parameter, $x$. I want to show that this function is well defined. In order to show it, I could alredy prove thet $t\to f(t,x)=e^{-t}t^{x-1}$ is measurable, and that for all $t\in\mathbb{R}_0^+$ and some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^+$ the limit of the function exists.

However, my third condition to finally prove it is well defined is the following:

> There exists a function $g(t)$ integrable over $\mathbb{R}_0^+$ such that $|f(t,x)|\leq g(t)~\forall t\in\mathbb{R}_0^+~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^+$

I can't find an upper bond that depends only on the variable $x$. I've tried with $x^{x-1}$ but it won't work, and I can always find a way to break that bound. Maybe I have to take a different approach to show it's well defined (doing the integral, using series criteria, etc) but I need to use the theorem about integrals that depend on the parameter and the only condition I can't show is the one I quoted.

Comment: Clarification question: you mention $f(t, x)$ in your question--what is that exactly?

Comment: $f(t,x)=e^{-t}t^{x-1}$, the function inside.

Answer (score 2):

An upper bound that depends only on the variable $x$ is
$$
\Gamma(x) <  \frac{\sqrt{2\pi} \cdot e^{1/12x} \cdot x^x}{\sqrt{x}e^x}
$$

You can prove that the gamma function is well defined by proving that
$$
\int_0^\infty t^{x-1} e^{-t} \; \mathrm d t
$$
is convergent.

The proof can be found [here](http://math.stmarys-ca.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Andres-Diestra.pdf) beginning from page 8.

Comment: Just curious, how did you find that upper bound?

Comment: I needed to bound the function inside the integral.